# A Concurrent Tree implementation with consistent snapshot capability

Tags: tree, concurrency, kotlin

I have a tree in my application from which I need to periodically take a snapshot. I've been using locks so far, but after running into a few deadlock issues I decided to create a lock-free implementation. I'm using a *persistent* `Map` implementation together with an `actor`. My goals were:

- Consistent snapshot from the `Map` in a concurrent environment
- Flattened tree structure
- Thread safety when writing

I have completed a preliminary implementation, but I'm not 100% sure that my implementation is idiomatic. I'm not that concerned with complexity, as writes won't be often, but I really need the consistent snapshot and the thread safety. I'd like some guidance on the

- overall design
- idiomatic use of coroutines / persistent data structures
- possible design oversights or thread safety issues
- anything that I missed (it happened in the past that I wrote something and it turned out that there is a well-known algorithm that does the same but better)

So without further ado, this is the implementation:

```kotlin
// primary interfaces
import kotlinx.collections.immutable.PersistentList
import kotlinx.collections.immutable.persistentListOf
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.SupervisorJob
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.actor
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlin.math.max

interface Tree<D : Any> {

    // this is the flattened tree
    val descendants: Sequence<TreeNode<D>>
    val children: Sequence<TreeNode<D>>

    // children can only be created through a reference to a Tree or a TreeNode
    fun createChild(data: D? = null): TreeNode<D>

    companion object {

        fun <D : Any> create(): Tree<D> {
            return ConcurrentTree()
        }
    }
}

interface TreeNode<D : Any> {
    val data: D?
    val parent: TreeNode<D>?
    val hasParent: Boolean
        get() = parent != null
    val children: Sequence<TreeNode<D>>

    fun createChild(data: D? = null): TreeNode<D>

    fun remove()
}
```

The `TreeNode` implementations look like this:

```kotlin
open class ConcurrentTreeNode<D : Any>(
        override val parent: ConcurrentTreeNode<D>? = null,
        override val data: D? = null,
        private val tree: ConcurrentTree<D>
) : TreeNode<D> {

    override val children: Sequence<TreeNode<D>>
        get() = tree.children.filter { it.parent == this }

    override fun createChild(data: D?): ConcurrentTreeNode<D> {
        val parent = this
        return ConcurrentTreeNode(
                parent = this,
                data = data,
                tree = tree
        ).apply {
            tree.addChildTo(parent, this)
        }
    }

    override fun remove() {
        tree.remove(this)
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "TreeNode(data=$data)"
    }
}

private class RootNode<D : Any>(
        parent: ConcurrentTreeNode<D>? = null,
        data: D? = null,
        tree: ConcurrentTree<D>
) : ConcurrentTreeNode<D>(
        parent = parent,
        data = data,
        tree = tree
) {
    override fun remove() {
        throw RuntimeException("A root node can't be removed.")
    }
}
```

And this is the `Tree` implementation:

```kotlin
class ConcurrentTree<D : Any> : Tree<D> {

    sealed class Message {

        data class AddChildTo<D : Any>(
                val parent: TreeNode<D>,
                val child: TreeNode<D>
        ) : Message()

        data class DeleteChild<D : Any>(
                val child: TreeNode<D>
        ) : Message()
    }

    private val treeScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + SupervisorJob())

    private val actor = treeScope.actor<Message> {
        for (msg in channel) { // iterate over incoming messages
            when (msg) {
                is AddChildTo<*> -> {
                    val (parent, child) = msg
                    val lastChildIdx = backend.indexOfLast { it.parent == parent }
                    val parentIdx = backend.indexOf(parent)
                    val idx = max(lastChildIdx, parentIdx) + 1
                    backend = if (idx == backend.lastIndex) {
                        backend.add(child as TreeNode<D>)
                    } else {
                        backend.add(idx, child as TreeNode<D>)
                    }
                }
                is Message.DeleteChild<*> -> {
                    val parent = msg.child.parent
                    val child = msg.child
                    val toDelete = backend
                            .dropWhile { it !== child }
                            .takeWhile { it === child || it.parent !== parent }
                    backend = backend.removeAll(toDelete)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private val root = RootNode(
            parent = null,
            data = null,
            tree = this
    )
    private var backend: PersistentList<TreeNode<D>> = persistentListOf(root)

    override val descendants: Sequence<TreeNode<D>>
        get() = backend.asSequence().drop(1)

    override val children: Sequence<TreeNode<D>>
        get() = root.children

    override fun createChild(data: D?) = root.createChild(data)

    fun addChildTo(parent: TreeNode<D>, child: TreeNode<D>) {
        treeScope.launch {
            actor.send(AddChildTo(parent, child))
        }
    }

    fun remove(node: TreeNode<D>) {
        treeScope.launch {
            actor.send(Message.DeleteChild(node))
        }
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Tree(descendants=${descendants.joinToString()})"
    }
}
```

Complexity of operations is `O(n)`, but more importantly snapshot creation is `O(1)`, as I'm using a `PersistentList` as a backend for the whole thing.

The operations (apart from the snapshot) are eventually consistent, but this doesn't matter in my case, I only want to see an operation either completed successfully or the previous state.

Can I do better? Is this idiomatic Kotlin code?

Comment: I would be really helpfull for me, if you could include imports to your code snippets so I can copy/paste it in my IDE without having to think about, if we have he same implementation.

Comment: of course, one moment

Comment: I added the missing imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following points are my personal, subjective suggestions based on my own experiece and understanding of your domain. I din't check if the solution is feasable but analyzed it for itself.

**Some suggestions** are **explicetely commented or mentioned** in the post's text, some more are in form of the **modified code** in the snippets.

### Overall Design

- I would suggest to genereally **rethink** the cases where you decided to go for **nullability**. In my experience it is often better to get an "*Optinal is empty but expected XYZ*" exception, instead of "*NullPointerException at line 123*" which tells almost nothing.
- There are so many google results why casting is bad, so I just tell you - **avoid casting** for your `Message` classes. My proposal is to give the sealed class a Wildcard and the compiler will smart cast for you `sealed class Message<A : Any>`
- It is never too annoying to repeat: Favor **composition over inheritance** :) . Your open `ConcurrentTreeNode` will get complex very fast and all further overrides will not do it any favor.
- Avoid using `var`s, especially for fields and go for immutability - this gives you (almost always) thread safety

### Idiomatic use of coroutines

There are some things which are obselete and some others, which I would redesign, because I like it the other way - like readability and my own code style.

**Obsolete**:

- Using `actor` -> Go for `channels` and `flows` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412793/kotlin-coroutines-channel-vs-flow)), which give you more functionality, interoperability and future support

**I would do it the other way**:

- Create a `channel` to send and receive messages

  - Launch a coroutine which coverts a `channel` to a `flow` and consumes every message sequentially
- mark `send()` and `resume()` functions as `suspend` to send messages to your channel

  - force the caller to make use of coroutine context to be able to send those

### Modified implemention with suggestions

Some siggestions are in form of a comment, some are intrinsic in the way I modified the code.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.collections.immutable.PersistentList
import kotlinx.collections.immutable.persistentListOf
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.SupervisorJob
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.consumeAsFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

interface Tree<D : Any> {

    // Did you consider Sequences for some special intent? Reading the documentation, their implementation can differ
    // highly and it introduces uncertainty to your code

    val descendants: Sequence<TreeNode<D>>
    val children: Sequence<TreeNode<D>>

    fun createChild(data: D? = null): TreeNode<D>

    companion object {

        fun <D : Any> create(): Tree<D> { // I dislike public static code in general
            return ConcurrentTree()       // and see no practical use of this method - unless you want to hide the implementations
        }
    }
}

interface TreeNode<D : Any> {
    val data: D?
    val parent: TreeNode<D>? // I guess, if data is NULL then parent also has to be NULL (like in RootNode)?
    // If so, bundle them inside same class and make it nullable, so its impossible to break this relation by compiler

    val hasParent: Boolean // this would fit better as a function, like 'List.isEmpty()'
        get() = parent != null
    val children: Sequence<TreeNode<D>>

    fun createChild(data: D? = null): TreeNode<D>

    fun remove() // remove what? A bit hard to find out just by the interface what it does or supposed to remove
}

// -----------

// Do you really need inheritance? a.k.a - Favor delegation over inheritance
open class ConcurrentTreeNode<D : Any>(
    override val parent: ConcurrentTreeNode<D>? = null,
    override val data: D? = null,
    private val tree: ConcurrentTree<D>
) : TreeNode<D> {

    private val treeScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + SupervisorJob())

    override val children: Sequence<TreeNode<D>> = tree.children.filter { it.parent == this }

    override fun createChild(data: D?): ConcurrentTreeNode<D> {
        return ConcurrentTreeNode(
            parent = this,
            data = data,
            tree = tree
        ).apply {
            treeScope.launch {
                tree.addChildTo(this@ConcurrentTreeNode, this@apply) // very poor to modify fields of classes, even worse doing so after construction
            }
        }
    }

    override fun remove() {
        treeScope.launch { tree.remove(this@ConcurrentTreeNode) }
    }

    override fun toString(): String = "TreeNode(data=$data)"
}

private class RootNode<D : Any>(
    parent: ConcurrentTreeNode<D>? = null,
    data: D? = null,
    tree: ConcurrentTree<D>
) : ConcurrentTreeNode<D>(
    parent = parent,
    data = data,
    tree = tree
) {
    // Design flaw. Maybe rethink the structure and create a special Node which doesn't have this function at all
    override fun remove() = error("A root node can't be removed.")
}

class ConcurrentTree<D : Any> : Tree<D> {

    sealed class Message<A : Any> { // You need a Wildcard for parent sealed class to maintain concrete types of children

        // be careful when using wildcard types with equal letters!
        // Try to use always a different letter in same file and/or class

        data class AddChildTo<B : Any>(val parent: TreeNode<B>, val child: TreeNode<B>) : Message<B>()

        data class DeleteChild<B : Any>(val child: TreeNode<B>) : Message<B>()
    }

    private val channel = Channel<Message<D>>(Channel.BUFFERED) // choose the type you like here

    init {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + SupervisorJob()).launch {

            fun idx(msg: AddChildTo<D>): Int {
                val lastChildIdx = backend.indexOfLast { it.parent == msg.parent }
                val parentIdx = backend.indexOf(msg.parent)
                return maxOf(lastChildIdx, parentIdx) + 1
            }

            fun addDependingOnIdx(message: AddChildTo<D>) {
                when (val idx = idx(message)) { // poor variable naming 'idx'
                    backend.lastIndex -> backend.add(message.child)
                    else -> backend.add(idx, message.child)
                }
            }

            fun toDeleteElements(msg: DeleteChild<D>): List<TreeNode<D>> {
                val parent = msg.child.parent
                val child = msg.child
                return backend
                        .dropWhile { it !== child }
                        .takeWhile { it === child || it.parent !== parent }
            }

            fun modifyBackendFor(message: Message<D>) {
                when (message) {
                    is AddChildTo<D> -> addDependingOnIdx(message)
                    is DeleteChild<D> -> backend.removeAll(toDeleteElements(message))
                }
            }

            channel
                    .consumeAsFlow() // hot flow which guarantees sequential operations
                    .collect { msg -> modifyBackendFor(msg) }
        }
    }

    // private val root = RootNode(parent = null, data = null, tree = this)
    //
    // --> there is no need for a field here and it doesn't harm to create such a small object, unless you go for
    // very large numbers. Fields are like global variables - highly doubtful when not actually needed

    private val backend: PersistentList<TreeNode<D>> = persistentListOf(RootNode(tree = this)) // VAL instead of VAR!

    override val descendants: Sequence<TreeNode<D>>
        get() = backend.asSequence().drop(1) // not thread safe. Btn: Weird to have un-deterministic behaviour for a getter
    // since the backend can be modified

    override val children: Sequence<TreeNode<D>> by lazy { RootNode(tree = this).children }

    override fun createChild(data: D?) = RootNode(tree = this).createChild(data)

    suspend fun addChildTo(parent: TreeNode<D>, child: TreeNode<D>) = channel.send(AddChildTo(parent, child))

    suspend fun remove(node: TreeNode<D>) = channel.send(DeleteChild(node))

    override fun toString(): String = "Tree(descendants=${descendants.joinToString()})"
}
```

---

PS: This review & analysis was done in ~4 hours

Comment: I went for nullability, because this will only be used from Kotlin and the Kotlin devs themsevelves suggest to use `null` in these cases. Thank you for your humongous effort!

Comment: There won't be any more implementors of `ConcurrentTreeNode`, that's why I picked inheritance. I don't see how this can be implemented using composition instead that's not much more complex.

Comment: The only place where I'm using `var`s is the `PersistentList`, but it is necessary because a `PersistentList` is immutable. This is what enables consistent snapshots.

Comment: What are the advantages of a hot `Flow`?

Comment: @AdamArold advantage compared to what? Actors will not be supported in near future, so there is the obvious one. The rest is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412793/kotlin-coroutines-channel-vs-flow) and [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html).

Comment: We don't know what comes next, but in the relevant KEEP they say that `actor` will be present until complex actors arrive.

Comment: @AdamArold good to know, I thought actors will be gone completely. For me flows are easy to use with very familiar api (collections) and at the end of the day, people use whats looks common and simple ..

Comment: I'm following the convo on the relevant issue [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/87). As I've figured out your solution is better, because it works in a multiplatform project as well. I didn't use the `Flow` in the end though, just the `Channel` and a coroutine.